# How to update Angular from 1.3 to 1.4

Tags: angularjs, bower

I would like to upgrade my Angular app from version 1.3 to 1.4 but I'm worried I might make a hash of it. Therefore, I wanted to ask this question first.

Here is my `bower.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "my app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.3.x",
    "angular-animate": "~1.3.x",
    "angular-resource": "~1.3.x",
    "angular-sanitize": "~1.3.x",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.15",
    "jquery": "~2.1.1",
    "semantic-ui": "~2.0.0",
    "angular-elastic-input": "~2.0.1",
    "angular-sweetalert": "~1.0.4",
    "angular-marked": "~0.0.14",
    "angular-highlightjs": "~0.4.1",
    "angular-nanoscroller": "~0.2.1",
    "angular-gravatar": "~0.4.1",
    "angular-cookies": "~1.4.8" //this needs updated version of Angular
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "~1.3.x"
  }
}
```

Is it simple a case of changing the angular setting to `~1.4.x` and running `bower update` or is there anything else I need to be aware of?

Answer (score 2):

You can also do

```
bower install angular#1.4
```

Passing the `--save` flag to above command will also update it in the `bower.json` file.

Answer (score 1):

```
bower install angular#1.4
```

and then persist or don't persist your changes in resolutions, or else you change your version in "dependencies" itself if you have decided to migrate, and then simply run:

`bower install`

Comment: @shashank agrawal's answer is a better one, you don't have to change the file bower.json manually, you will be taken through interactively, but can't delete this answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the version number from `~1.3.x` to `~1.4.x` in `bower.json` and then running `bower update` will do the trick.

Keep in mind though that when you update your packages that nothing is solely dependent on that specific version, otherwise you'll be asked to intervene during the installation. Running bower update by its self will attempt to update everything in your package, so if that's not what you want to do I suggest targeting angular specifically like Shahank suggested.